# Selector in Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

As I'm newbie for cocos2D in Android but having some experience in ios, what I intend is that on clicking on my CCMenuItem I should fire an event...the same in IOS environment is done by specifying the selector at last argument, so how a selector or possibly a local function/procedure will be called in Android development to achieve the same requirement.

Comment: i didnt get you what you want to say ,will you plz rephrase your questions..

Comment: Rahul, what I want when I click on the start button at my menu which is in Android, I can show different scene..for this in iPhone we use selector, so in Android how could I do the same?

Comment: impleted selector from this link http://www.blazin.in/2016/03/how-to-use-selectors-for-botton.html it working for me simple solution Thakns :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got how to do that... I'm lucid for guys which ever or in future face such problem, so they can sort out.Please, feel free to ask in case of any query.

As for answer part, please check out following link:
http://pastie.org/5426180